# IIS Server .m3u8 extension not opening

Tags: http-status-code-404, iis-7.5

I have a file called mystream.m3u8 that I'm trying to open from my iphone. I can see it on my server but when I open it from my iPhone and iPad it shows me 404 error. Not really sure why it's happening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, IIS doesn't know how to treat `.m3u8` files. See [this](http://forums.iis.net/t/1175840.aspx):

> You need to add mime types settings for both .m3u8 and .ts extension. The settings will look like:
>
> ```
> <mimeMap fileExtension=".m3u8" mimeType="application/x-mpegURL" />
> <mimeMap fileExtension=".ts" mimeType="video/MP2T" />
> ```

(copypasted in case iis.net is reorganized or something).

Comment: I now got the m3u8 to load but the .ts still shows 404 error.

Oh never mind I was using an IP instead of the the host name. Got it to work. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: You may also need to add the following above the lines above:
      <remove fileExtension=".m3u8"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".ts"/>